# Why some types from my library don't autocomplete when using in a project

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have my own library where I have my basic components as inputs, containers, etc.

The library bundles in my project same as any 3rd party library.
The problem is that when using it in my project, the types which are imported from another file in the library don't autocomplete but if I define all the types within the same file which I export the component they autocomplete correctly.

Seems like it is not resolving the types when they are not in the same file. They resolve well within the library but not in the exported bundle.

For example,
The following works well:

```
interface IInputProps{ ......}

const input=({inputProps:IInputProps})=>.....
```

The following works well in the library but does not autocomplete the types:

```
 import {IInputProps} from './Types'

 const input=({inputProps:IInputProps})=>....
```

Any idea?

This is my tsconfig.json in my library:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "es5"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "dist/library",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "types": ["node", "lodash", "jest", "sortablejs"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/typings/*.d.ts",
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/ui-lib/src/typings/*.d.ts",
      "node_modules/jest-canvas-mock/types/index.ts"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/mylib-ui/typings/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/ui-library/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.*", "src/**/*.md", "dist"]
}
```

My webpack configuration in my library is:

```
 {
    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i, 
   include: [srcPath, uiLibraryPath], 
    use: [
             'babel-loader', //javascript files loader
                    {
                    loader: 'ts-loader', //typescript loader
                    options: {
                            allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                            transpileOnly: true, 
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
```

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: yes, all works good. I am not sure if it could be something about vsCode. But I checked my settings and Typescript>Suggest:Paths is enabled

Comment: Are you sure it compiles, with the tsconfig you're showing, and not other config, ts-node, babel, any bundler, etc. ?

Comment: it compiles with webpack,so you mean that tsconfig is not related to compilation in this case?. I am not clear about how webpack and tsconfig are connected or if they are.

Comment: @astef I just updated my question with my webpack configuration related to typescript